# how to use a wxPython Grid and GridTableBase?

Tags: wxpython

I've searched high and low, but I can't find a **recent** example **anywhere**.

I have some data: column headers in one list and rows in another list.  I'd like to add them to a Grid using a GridTableBase.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a demo after all, I just didn't know about it and didn't stumble across it (and might not have recognized it if I did!) - https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/ - download the demo corresponding to your version and look for 'GridCustTable.py'